# Telegram sending message to all contacts

Tags: telegram

Using telegram to send message to all my contacts . Hey does anybody know if telegram app has an option to send message to all contacts ? There is no answer in the faq, and there is no such an option.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [telegram CLI](https://github.com/vysheng/tg)

Have a look at all the CLI commands here:
https://github.com/vysheng/tg/wiki/Telegram-CLI-Commands

to get the contact list, there is `contact_list`. By parsing the output, you can get the single contacts.

send msgs to all of them by any of the `send_...` command.

u can use both lua and python for that.

Comment: Do not post link-only answers.

Answer (score 1):

In Telegram application No, there is no option to do this

But you can write an application for your self to do this

and use this function

messages.sendMessage#4cde0aab peer:InputPeer message:string random_id:long = messages.SentMessage;

to send a message to all members in your contact list

The only parameters changes in your loop are peer (user_id) and random_id

That's it


Good Luck !!!

Comment: Hi bahram.Could u please introduce a code sample. It's not easy to use Telegram API. thanks

Comment: Search My name in Google, Call me ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can even do that using telegram's channel feature. 
You add all your contacts there as there is no limitation set for that. Then you can broadcast your messages to all of them.